# setting purchase price from not from shopp price module[Shopplugin]

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopp

I used to do this with Pricing & Product set to donation and price from non-shopp script is send to next steps as a donation amount, so user can't change quantity becouse it's combined with donation amount. it's probalbly this same var. the next defect is that I can't set product shipping cost.i think that I chose the wrong way to this and the right way is set Pricing & Product to normal option "shipping". but if I choose this option I don't have clue how to set price from not shopp module. I can't use bulid in pricing module becouse is too many variants, the configurator have 22 options..

Comment: better to post some part of code and ask the question, from the part of your code, where, you are facing the problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for response, it's not strict coding question it's ask if it's even posible to set price when Pricing & Product is set to normal option "shipping".

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`shopp('product', 'input');`](https://shopplugin.net/api/product-input/). This works for products with variations that don't affect the price. For instance when a t-shirt comes in 22 colors and 4 sizes and all sell for the same price.

Variations can grow fast. When you have a product with 3 variations with each 4 options, you are actually adding 4x4x4 (=64) product(price)s. Sometimes it is better to rethink the way you are creating products.